# FutureBuilder Issues with loading new data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am attempting to implement a play button, that when clicked will play a selected audio file from a ListTile.

Here is the code for getting the filepath from the list tile:

```
Future getPath() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var selectedCard = prefs.getInt('selectedIndex');
    var selectedPath = prefs.getString('selectedPath') ?? "";
    
    return selectedPath;
  }
```

Here is where the play button is built:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AudioPlayerController audioController =
        Provider.of<AudioPlayerController>(context, listen: true);

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getPath(),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            String path = snapshot.data.toString();
            var apc = AudioPlayerController(path.toString());
            return StreamProvider(
                initialData: apc.playingState ?? PlayState.ready,
                create: (_) => apc.playingStateStream,
                builder: (context, child) {
                  return Container(
                      child: FloatingActionButton(
                          heroTag: "Play",
                          backgroundColor: AppColor.AppLightBlueColor,
                          foregroundColor: AppColor.AppDarkBlueColor,
                          focusColor: AppColor.AppLightBlueColor,
                          splashColor: AppColor.AppLightBlueColor,
                          elevation: 0,
                          onPressed: () async {

                            if (apc.playingState == PlayState.playing) {
                              await apc.pause();
                            } else if (apc.playingState == PlayState.ready) {
                              await apc.setSource(path);
                              await apc.play();
                            } else if (apc.playingState == PlayState.paused) {
                              await apc.resume();
                            }
                          },
                          child: StreamBuilder(
                              stream: apc.playingStateStream,
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                switch (snapshot.data) {
                                  case PlayState.playing:
                                    return const Icon(
                                      Icons.pause,
                                      size: 50,
                                    );
                                  case PlayState.paused:
                                    return const Icon(
                                      Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                                      size: 50,
                                    );
                                  default:
                                    debugPrint("Default");
                                    // stderr.writeln(snapshot);
                                    return const Icon(
                                      Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                                      size: 50,
                                    );
                                }
                              })));
```

Here is where the path comes from in the ListTile:

```
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              elevation: 0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: borderRadius,
                          color: selectedIndex == index
                              ? AppColor.HighlightTileColor
                              : AppColor.AppLightBlueColor),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 9,
                      child: ListTile(
                        selected: selectedIndex == index,
                        shape:
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: borderRadius),
                        onTap: () async {
                          SharedPreferences prefs =
                              await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                          prefs.setInt('selectedIndex', index);
                          prefs.setString('selectedPath', file1);
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                            // selectedPath = file1;
                          });
```

The issue I am facing, is that the play button works to play and pause audio properly, but the futurebuilder is not updating when selecting a new listtile.

Tried to implement a setState inside of the getPath() function, but it created an infinite loop

Comment: Share the code for your ListTile. You seem to be storing the index and path of the selected file in shared preference. So, in the `onTap` method of your `ListTile`, save the index and path of the clicked ListTile item in shared preference.

Comment: @Subash You are correct, my problem is updating the play button to play the proper tile from the shared preference selection

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified, thats how the code previously was. The futurebuilder still does not update @Subash

Comment: the problem might be because, you called setState from the widget containing ListTile, but this did not cause the widget with futureBuilder to rebuild. Include complete widgets for better understanding.

Comment: No.  `future: getPath(),` Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a `Future` is completed, even if you use `setState`, it will not re-run but use the previous result during the current build. To make it refresh, you need to define the future  as a variable in a member of a stateful widget's state class, and assign a new value to it with `setState`.

So convert it into a stateful class if it is not stateful yet, and add a member variable:

```
late Future<String> _getPathFuture;
```

In an `initState` function, assign an initial value to it:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _getPathFuture =  getPath();
}
```

You also have to modify `getPath` to indicate its return type:

```
Future<String> getPath() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var selectedCard = prefs.getInt('selectedIndex');
  var selectedPath = prefs.getString('selectedPath') ?? "";
    
  return Future.value(selectedPath);
}
```

Now use this variable in the `FutureBuilder`, set type here as well to `String`:

```
return FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _getPathFuture,
  ...
);
```

After this, once you are sure that the new values are saved to shared preferences, call `setState` like:

```
setState(() {
  _getPathFuture = getPath();
});
```

Two comments:

1. Writing to the shared preferences is async. To make sure the write operation is complete, use `await prefs.setInt...`.
2. Since reading shared preferences is sync, the entire `FutureBuilder` is only needed because `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` is async. But there is no real reason to read its value every time you access is. You can save this value somewhere in you app when it starts up, even in `main` function, store it so that you can access it from you app.

Comment: What a great answer. Kudos to you